# Guess the String given Random Triplets

Tags: algorithm

Given an unknown string, execute an utility function, called

```
string returnRandomTripletFromString(string)
```

the function returns a random triplet from the unknown string, you are also given length of the string

the random triplet returned by the utility function, would maintain the relative order of letters in string,

Lets say the string is helloworld
it would return

'hel', 'wod', 'lor'

but it would never return

'lhd'

since h is before l in the string

How can you guess the string using this utility function, using minimum number of calls to the function.

Comment: What string are the letters in your "triplets" coming from?  I thought you were using "HelloWorld" as an example input.  And what is password?  I think your wording is confusing.

Comment: This still doesn't make sense - if the actual string is "HelloWorld" then where does the "b" and "k" come from in "bok"?

Comment: Before you call this function, do you have a collection of all possible answers?

Comment: no you don't have all possible answers, you only know length of the string

Comment: OK, can you explain where the `b` and `k` come from in `bok`?

Comment: I updated the description read again

Comment: `b` and `k` are not in the string `helloworld` - Are you saying that letters that aren't in the string can be returned in the triplets?

Comment: Given your description, there's no guarantee that you could ever determine the string unless you know that the utility function will eventually return all possible triplets. In your example, will the function ever return `"owo"` more than once? What about `"hel"`?

Comment: yes the function will eventually return all of the possible triplets, and it won't return the same triplet again, so it remembers which triplet it has already returned and will not returned it again.

Comment: It is probably not required that you get ALL POSSIBLE triplets to solve, just a "sufficient" number of them, which will vary depending on the length of the original word. Of course if you are not given enough, it will be impossible.

Comment: Re-worded: "Give a function a getRandomTripplet() 

which returns a random triplet of letters from a string. You don't know the string using calls to this function you have to correctly guess the string. the length of the string is also given. 

Lets say the string is helloworld the function getRandomTriplet will return things like 

hlo 
hew 
wld 
owo 
the function maintains the relative order of the letters. so it will never return

ohl since h is before o in the string. 
owe since w is after e 

The string is not known you are only given length of the string."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can happen after calling the random triplet function *multiple* times.

> Suppose our string was "hello"

Let calling random triplet function gives the following on every call but not necessarily in this order:

> ell 
> llo 
> hel 
> hlo 
> elo

If I create a graph from the characters I get from the random triplet function:

[image]

From this graph, I can only interpret that starting letter may be

> 'H'

and ending letter may be

> 'O'
>
> Then if I find the longest path in the graph. I will get "hello" or "olleh" depending upon where I begin from.

Also the number of nodes visited in the path will be equal to the length of the string.

Assumption :

1. I could create this graph only after calling random triplet function
   multiple times.
2. Each time I get unique triplets from the random function to construct the graph

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer as it is by far the most complete. An algorithm in some language showing the construction of the graph would be nice, along with the subsequent parsing of it for possible words.

Answer (score 1):

I'm treating 'bok' as disallowed in your example.

in general it can be very difficult, suppose the target string was "10101010"
them all possible substring are possible, if it is known what bias the random function which picks the triplets has it may be possible to use statistical analysis to deconvolve the distribution of yielding the original

one approach cpuld be
1 determine which characters comprise the string,
2 try different combinations of those characters until you find one that yields a similar distribution of results.

the statistical rules that govern the proportions od each result are a system of linear equations so it may be possible to attempt a simultaneous  solution to these equations

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any possible way to find the original string by getting those random "triplets" out of it, since there is no way to find the string's length. However, if the string's length is known, the problem could be solved by doing consecutive calls to the function and then doing advanced comparison work with its output. But this is also going to be quite complicated, IMHO.
EDIT: still impossible, IMHO, even if the string length is known. It would only be 100% possible if we had a guarantee that there are no repetitive characters in the string. Otherwise, consider a really long string with repeated letters and patterns of letters. Using information from those "triplets", it is, IMHO, impossible to reconstruct such a string.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you have a list of all the possible strings?

I would try reducing the list by searching for which strings contain
 the first letter. If an item does contain the character, then save
 the index of the character associated with the string. If an item
 does not contain the character then remove it from the list.

Loop through the other characters in the triplet, find the first instance of each character after the index of the last character found (remove if does not contain)

After you have finished looping through a triplet, if there are still multiple options left, then get a new triplet until all other remaining options have been eliminated.

#Note: to make up for situations where the string being sought has only 3 letters/a pattern that is matched by multiple other strings. Then you can analyze the occurrence of each letter and compare it to the predicted occurrence from the string. You can make this more accurate by paying attention to the relative occurrence of each letter

Comment: No, you don't have ANY possible answers to start with. At the end, you may have multiple possible answers. The original wording of this problem asks you to "guess" the answer, implying that you may get multiple solutions, but among them at least one will be correct.

Comment: The question has changed since I wrote this, if you look at the older answers you'll see that the question was trying to get the original word from the triplet. This IS impossible, unless you have a list of words. You can use an algorithm to check if something seems like a word, but you'll never know if it is.

Comment: It's very frustrating when you answer a question, and then it is completely changed. Jasen and Mints97 answers were for the original question as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getstring(triplets):
    r = list(set([i for l in triplets for i in l]))
    for l in triplets:
        fix(r, l[1], l[2])
        fix(r, l[0], l[1])
    return ''.join(r)

def fix(l, a, b):
    if l.index(a) > l.index(b):
        l.remove(a)
        l.insert(l.index(b), a)
```

This is the code if there if no character repeats, quite straight forward as Mints97 pointed out.